# How to printing crystal report directly to network printer in C# .Net Windows

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

i read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680315/how-to-printing-crystal-report-directly-to-network-printer-in-vb-net-or-c-net-i) Link

Answer Given is -
 report.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "\network\printer"
Please Give me e.g.What is Network(ip Address or PC Name)
My Printer Name Shows in Property is "EPSON TX121 Series on DRAGONFRUIT-PC"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

report.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "\\\\remotePCName\\printerName"