# How do I disable the print preview in sap crystal reports using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I want to print receipts without showing the print preview window. Is it possible to have it print to the default printer connected to the pc without print preview?

**This is my current code:**

```
    Private Sub BTPRINT_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BTPRINT.Click

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    With dt
        .Columns.Add("Articulo")
        .Columns.Add("Cantidad")
        .Columns.Add("Precio")

    End With
    For Each dgr As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
        dt.Rows.Add(dgr.Cells(0).Value, dgr.Cells(1).Value, dgr.Cells(2).Value)
    Next

    Dim reportdocument As CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
    reportdocument = New CrystalReport2
    reportdocument.SetDataSource(dt)
    Form3.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdocument

    Form3.ShowDialog()
    Form3.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: This any help to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680315/how-to-printing-crystal-report-directly-to-network-printer-in-vb-net-or-c-net-i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was extremly simple.

**I removed:**

```
Form3.ShowDialog()
Form3.Dispose()
```

**and swapped it with:**

```
reportdocument.PrintToPrinter(0, False, 1, 1)
```